# Do most modern freezers have compressor delay?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, compressor

Do most modern freezers have a "failsafe" of some kind to keep the compressor from cycling too quickly? I want to connect my freezer to an external thermostat and I have been advised that this can kill the compressor if the freezer does not have "compressor delay."

Comment: Is there something about your freezers thermostat that you don’t trust it and want to bypass it by using an external thermostat?

Comment: We would need the model number to know for sure. Where I have seen delays is on fridge with electronic controls . If you just have a rotary dial it probably doesn’t have a delay but make sure you have a dead band adjustment (you don’t want it to be turning on and off in less than a minute 3 minutes is better.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in the Avanti CF24Q0W, mostly.

Comment: Without extra electronics you want to avoid the one bad situation: turning on the compressor when it has been running recently. I killed one leaving it on a power supply which switched a lot as it was running on "surplus" power from a solar system.

Comment: @Ed Beal when you say to make sure I have a dead band adjustment: Is there something easy that I can do upstream of the freezer to ensure this?

Comment: Your new controller,,, if you turn on at one temp then turn off -1 or even -4 the system can turn in and off two often so most controllers have PID loops or Dead band that keeps the compressor from cycling on off two often  most of the energy star compressors are small compared to when I first started with R12 , the compressors are sized to run longer and or at a variable speed because starting is the highest energy draw 3-5 x is normal starting current but I have measured over 8x for a few seconds so keeping the system running longer with less starts extends the compressor life and reduces $